# In a list with two values seperated by a delimiter, accessing the second field in the second column

Tags: python, list

I have the following code, and would like the most efficient method of returning the subject, for any given teacher:

Note: the list alldata holds the data in the format:

```
['Mr Moose : Maths', 'Mr Goose: History', 'Mrs Marvin: Computing']
```

in which 'Mr Moose: Maths' is the first element in the list. 
I wish to get at Maths and History and Computing, for any given teacher that is searched for.

**Code**

```
#Search for a teacher, and return the subject they teach
"""File contents
Mr Moose : Maths
Mr Goose: History
Mrs Cook: English

"""

alldata=[]
col_num=0
teacher_names=[]
delimiter=":"

def main():
      with open("teacherbook.txt") as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                  alldata.append((line.strip()))
            print(alldata)


            print()
            print()

            for x in alldata: 
                   teacher_names.append(x.split(delimiter)[col_num].strip()) 


            teacher=input("Enter teacher you are looking for:")
            if teacher in teacher_names: 
                  print("..and the subject they teach is:",teacher_names[2])
            else:
                  print("No")

main()
```

I'd be interested to know if this code could just be fixed by adding a simple line to where I have teacher_names[2] and/or any solution that is more elegant, i.e shows how to search a file directly for a given name (e.g. Mr Moose) and returns the next field (in this case Maths). The process here does seem arduous as opposed to what it would be using csv handling.

Comment: Is the first element of each element in the list unique? If so why not just parse them into a dictionary?

Comment: Choose a different data-structure. It makes no sense using such a string, then parsing the string. Just use a dictionary, or even a list of tuples.

Comment: Also, as an aside, don't use `for line in f.readlines()`, just use `for line in f`. The latter is much more efficient, it reads the lines one-by-one, and you don't have to read the entire file into memory and materialize a list of lines like the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend converting your list into a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)ionary for quick and easy lookup.

This is how you can convert your list to a dictionary:

```
In [550]: t_list = ['Mr Moose : Maths', 'Mr Goose: History', 'Mrs Marvin: Computing']

In [556]: t_dict = dict(tuple(map(str.strip, x.split(':'))) for x in t_list); t_dict
Out[556]: {'Mr Goose': 'History', 'Mr Moose': 'Maths', 'Mrs Marvin': 'Computing'}
```

As pointed out, if you can guarantee a space around `:`, you can shorten  `map(str.strip, x.split(':'))` to `x.split(' : ')`.

Now, if you want the subject a certain teacher teaches, all you need to do is use dict indexing to get it:

```
In [557]: t_dict['Mr Moose']
Out[557]: 'Maths'
```

Comment: If you are confident that your data will always be well formed you could replace `map(str.strip, x.split(':'))` with `x.split(' : ')`

Edit: Aaaaand ignore me, as I had misread the example data.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, a dictionary lookup is best. Another approach to solve the problem:

```
>>> with open('teacherbook.txt') as teacher_file:
...     alldata = [line.split(':') for line in teacher_file]
# [['Mr Moose', 'Maths'], ['Mr Goose', 'History'], ... ]


>>> teacher_dict = {line[0]: line[1].strip() for line in alldata}
# {'Mr Moose': 'Maths', 'Mr Goose': 'History', ... }
```